# Caliburn Micro - coroutines - UI thread blocked unexpectedly

Tags: wpf, multithreading, caliburn.micro, coroutine

I use Caliburn Micro's coroutines for a workflow that also shows screens in WPF.

I made this IDisposable construct for a busy-screen: wrap a using statement around a long running job, and a busy screen will be shown during that job.  When the using block ends, Dispose() will hide the busy screen behind the scenes.

The using-scope construction shows and hides the busy screen using ..

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(...show/hide form...)
```

.. to make it happen on the UI Thread:

An example of usage:

```
yield return new TaskResult(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  using (_dialogController.ShowDialogForUsingScope(new BusyViewModel() 
                       { Message = "Account gegevens ophalen..." }))
  {
     _securityContext.RefreshAccountFromServer();
  }
  using (_dialogController.ShowDialogForUsingScope(new BusyViewModel() 
                       { Message = "You see me..." }))
  {
     _securityContext.RefreshAccountFromServer();
  }
}));
```

This works perfectly: the busy screen shows, work is done, it's removed, immediately followed by another busy screen during the second job and done :)

But when i do it with 2 yield returns the second job is run on the UI thread anyway:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ", IsBackground: " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground);
yield return new TaskResult(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ", IsBackground: " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground);
    using (_dialogController.ShowDialogForUsingScope(new BusyViewModel() { Message = "Account gegevens ophalen..." }, 2000))
    {
        _securityContext.RefreshAccountFromServer();
    }
}));
Debug.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ", IsBackground: " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground);
yield return new TaskResult(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ", IsBackground: " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground);
    using (_dialogController.ShowDialogForUsingScope(new BusyViewModel() { Message = "You never see me..." }, 2000))
    {
    }
}));
```

resulting in:

```
Thread: 9, IsBackground: False
Thread: 12, IsBackground: True
Thread: 9, IsBackground: False
Thread: 9, IsBackground: False --> 9 too ??
```

This explains why it freezes, but why is the task not on another thread?

Comment: just as a note, tag future questions about Caliburn.Micro with the caliburn.micro tag, because the old framework isn't maintained any more.

Comment: thanks, i knew this, but didn't know how to enter Caliburn Micro as a tag, but it's with a dot :)

Answer (score 2):

After googling a lot more, i found this thorough answer:

[Is Task.Factory.StartNew() guaranteed to use another thread than the calling thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245935/is-task-factory-startnew-guaranteed-to-use-another-thread-than-the-calling-thr)

Seems the task scheduler is in some situations tempted to run a task in the requesting thread (being synchronously in the UI thread in my case).

To prevent that, you need to pass the default scheduler when starting a task, instead of the Current (which is the default behavior):

Example:

```
yield return new TaskResult(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (_dialogController.ShowDialogForUsingScope(new BusyViewModel() { Message = "Inloggen..." }, 800))
                {
                    // do stuff
                }
            }, 
            CancellationToken.None, 
            TaskCreationOptions.None, 
            TaskScheduler.Default));
```