# Convert APM Iterative calls to TAP

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Since [MS had said that both APM and EAP are outdated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx), TAP is the recommended approach to asynchronous programming in the .NET Framework. Then I want to convert my code from APM to TAP:

```
public class RpcHelper
{
    public void DoReadViaApm(IRpc rpc, BlockingCollection<ArraySegment<byte>> bc)
    {
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        rpc.BeginRead(buf, 0, buf.Length,
            ar =>
            {
                IRpc state = (IRpc) ar.AsyncState;
                try
                {
                    int nb = state.EndRead(ar);
                    if (nb > 0)
                    {
                        bc.Add(new ArraySegment<byte>(buf, 0, nb));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ignored)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    DoReadViaApm(state, bc);
                }
            }, 
            rpc);
    }

    public void DoReadViaTap(IRpc rpc, BlockingCollection<ArraySegment<byte>> bc)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Task<byte[]> task = rpc.ReadAsync();
                try
                {
                    task.Wait(-1);
                    if (task.Result != null && task.Result.Length > 0)
                    {
                        bc.Add(new ArraySegment<byte>(task.Result));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ignored)
                {
                }
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
}

public interface IRpc
{
    IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state);
    int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult);

    Task<byte[]> ReadAsync();
}
```

The TAP method DoReadViaTap() use TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, it looks very ugly. Can I make DoReadViaTap() looks better like DoReadViaApm() ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what your code is supposed to do, but I guess it's some worker waiting for input?
You could simplify it by using `await` and make the started operation asynchronous. Be aware that a task has a timeout, so you might want to set that appropriately or catch the exception.

```
public void DoReadViaTap(IRpc rpc, BlockingCollection<ArraySegment<byte>> bc)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] result = await rpc.ReadAsync();
            if (result.Length > 0)
            {
                bc.Add(new ArraySegment<byte>(result));
            }
            catch (AggregateException ignored)
            {
            }
        }
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

Comment: You code looks better, but not what I expected. I want to kill the long running task, because DoReadViaApm() only use IO thread shortly.

Comment: You mean the task created by `Task.Factory.StartNew()`? You could use a cancellation token to check if that task is supposed to be cancelled.
[Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19932396/2300387)

Comment: Where did the `try` go? The `catch` won't compile without it.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to use `async`-`await`. And when you do that, you don't need to start a `Task`:

```
public async Task DoReadViaTap(IRpc rpc, BlockingCollection<ArraySegment<byte>> bc)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] result = await rpc.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (result != null && result.Length > 0) // or result?.Length > 0 on C# 6
            {
                bc.Add(new ArraySegment<byte>(result));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ignored)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

To me, this reads much better than the APM version.

Note that I don't think completely ignoring exceptions and infinite loops with no way to end them are good practices, I just copied those from your code.

Comment: I'm looks for a infinite chained task construction:

    start:
        Task task = rpc.ReadAsync();
        task.ContinueWith {
           bc.Add(new ArraySegment<byte>(result));
           goto start:
        }

Comment: @CauchySong Why? It's going to be more messy than using `async`-`await`, just like like your APM code.