# task.factory.startnew thread cancel with another comming request

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have a web service with just one method. the web service is working so simple. here is the part of my web service code:

```
    //submit transaction(s) into the database
    Simpay simpay = new Simpay { Account = account, Job = new SystemJob { ID = 0, TypeName = "SimpayHistory" } };
    Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(simpay.AddHistory);
```

as you can see Im using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` in order to do the task in another thread. but sometimes something wired happens. lets assume task factory take the thread number 300 and start doing its job. suddenly another request comes and it took the same thread!! so my first task just cancel!!(I'm not sure about it but its the only thing that i found in my logs!)
now i wonder is this possible? how can i avoid this?
here is part of my log file. as you can see another request comes and take the old one thread!!!(first line belong to the Task factory and second one belongs to the new request. thread number is 345)

```
[DEBUG];[2015-11-05 07:37:57,526];[345];[DataBase.Query line:56];[2.5646];[];[(Stored Procedure: ud_prc_simPayRetrieveLastTransaction)(Code: 1)(Message: No Error.)(SQL Parameters: @mobileNumber)]
[INFO ];[2015-11-05 07:37:57,667];[345];[Identity.DoesUserNameContentValid line:146];[0.0591];[];[(Message: user name content validation completed successfully.)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is what Job Skeet describes as re-entrance. I must refer you to his post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245935/is-task-factory-startnew-guaranteed-to-use-another-thread-than-the-calling-thr). He gives an in depth explanation of it.

A short answer is that it is possible for future executions of tasks to hijack existing ones and kill out their processes.